# Magento Observer core_block_abstract_to_html_after not triggering on homepage?

Tags: magento, module

I'm using a module that has a widget that amends the price html on the category product listing pages. However, my category listing on the homepage (brought through in a CMS block) does not cause this observer to react.

Any ideas why? Here's how it triggers in the module's config.xml:

```
<core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
            <observers>
                <pay4latercategory>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>pay4later/p4lProductWidget</class>
                    <method>categoryPageObserver</method>
                </pay4latercategory>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
```

I've tested it by print_r('foo') in the function categoryPageObserver, which works fine on the category listing pages, but not on the homepage. I call the category on the homepage like this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="52" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Any idea why this observer does not trigger on the homepage? Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What about blocks and full page caching? If content of whole block or even whole page is cached - events like `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` aren't triggered. Try delete cache and see, whether you observer was invoked on first page refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the response. All cache is currently disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Does `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` trigger?

You may want to look further into the `toHtml()` method of Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php around line ~790

Also ensure your module's output isn't disabled as `toHtml()` has a `return '';` before the event your trying to hook into.

Comment: Ah, yes, well, this certainly sheds some light onto why it's not displaying on the homepage. I'm not sure how to enable the output for the homepage, is the problem. Any ideas on where I can look, or is it all becoming a bit module-specific?